# Python/Glade/PyGTK - Check if Checkbox is Active

Tags: python, checkbox, pygtk, glade

After going through the PyGTK libraries and tutorials, I haven't managed to find an exact answer I'm looking for, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong...

Anyway, I'm learning PyGTK and Glade, I'm in the process of scripting a simple downloader application. The GUI of the application has three check boxes, and then a submit button.

What I'm trying to do is get the status of the check boxes after the submit button is pressed, that way I can continue my script to download applications based on whether the checkboxes are true or false.

Here's what I have so far. (Still very early stages and learning from mistakes)

**Python Script:**

```
import sys
try:
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")
except:
    pass
try:
    import gtk
    import gtk.glade
except:
    sys.exit(1)


class GladeTest:

    def __init__(self):

        #Set the Glade file
            filename = "gui.glade"
            builder = gtk.Builder()
            builder.add_from_file(filename)
            builder.connect_signals(self)

        #Create our dictionay and connect it
            dic = { "btnSubmit_clicked" : self.btnSubmit_clicked,
            "chkboxDropbox_toggled" : self.chkboxDropbox_toggled,
            "MainWindow_destroy" : gtk.main_quit }

        def btnSubmit_clicked(self, widget):
            self.button = gtk.ToggleButton("chkboxDropbox_toggled")
            status = self.button.get_active()
            print status

        def chkboxDropbox_toggled(self, widget):
            print ""




if __name__ == "__main__":
    hwg = GladeTest()
    gtk.main()
```

Glade 3 XML (gui.glade):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="2.24"/>
  <!-- interface-naming-policy project-wide -->
  <object class="GtkAction" id="action1"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="MainWindow">
    <property name="visible">True</property>
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">MainWindow</property>
    <property name="resizable">False</property>
    <property name="window_position">center</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="MainWindow_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVBox" id="vbox1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Downloader</property>
            <attributes>
              <attribute name="style" value="normal"/>
              <attribute name="size" value="300"/>
            </attributes>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkCheckButton" id="chkboxDropbox">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Dropbox</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
            <signal name="toggled" handler="chkboxDropbox_toggled" swapped="no"/>
            <signal name="activate" handler="chkboxDropbox_active" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkCheckButton" id="chkboxPython">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Python</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
            <signal name="toggled" handler="chkboxPython_checked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkCheckButton" id="chkboxChrome">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Google Chrome</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
            <signal name="toggled" handler="chkboxChrome_checked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">3</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="btnSubmit">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Download/Run</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="btnSubmit_clicked" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Either I can't find the proper method of calling for the status, or I have found it and I'm just using it wrong... Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to call "get_active" method of gtk checkbox, get object of check button from glade file and call "get_active" method on click event of submit button.

here, code snippet to be more descriptive:

```
class GladeTest:

    def __init__(self):

        #Set the Glade file
        filename = "gui.glade"
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(filename)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        #Create our dictionay and connect it
        dic = { "btnSubmit_clicked" : self.btnSubmit_clicked,
        "chkboxDropbox_toggled" : self.chkboxDropbox_toggled,
        "MainWindow_destroy" : gtk.main_quit }

    def btnSubmit_clicked(self, widget):
        chkbt_chrome = self.builder.get_object("chkboxChrome")
        print "ACTIVE--",chkbt_chrome.get_active()
        # do same for rest of the check buttons

        self.button = gtk.ToggleButton("chkboxDropbox_toggled") # if used for check box status then there is no need for this button.

        status = self.button.get_active()
        print status

    def chkboxDropbox_toggled(self, widget):
        print ""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hwg = GladeTest()
    gtk.main()
```

hope, it would help you.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this callback:

```
def btnSubmit_clicked(self, widget):
    self.button = gtk.ToggleButton("chkboxDropbox_toggled")
    status = self.button.get_active()
    print status
```

what you are actually doing is creating a completely new toggle button, which is invisible because you're not adding it to any other widget, and then asking it for its status. That's why it's not responding as you expect.

Comment: Ah, I understand where I went wrong. Thanks a lot for the help!